# How to maintain a constant ImageView width and and height

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a recyclerView displaying a list of imageView(thumbnail size) and textView. Whenever i populate my textViews with lot of text, the imageView is shrinked and the height increases. The textView is also wrapped to the left  leaving lot of white space on the right. Below is an image of what i am talking about. How can i make the thumbnail width and height fixed even though my textView has a lot of texts, so as to maintain the image quality.

[image]

*axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:background="#E2E2E2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="63"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:text="Caption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:text="Caption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textColor="#808080"
                    android:text="Caption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/pub_date"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Just a note. If a ViewGroup has only one child then you most probably do not need to use it. In this case, you can eliminate the first LinearLayout, if you change the attributes of the second LinearLayout accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this javadoc for `setMaxWidth` method of ImageView:

> An optional argument to supply a maximum width for this view. Only
>   valid if setAdjustViewBounds(boolean) has been set to true. To set an
>   image to be a maximum of 100 x 100 while preserving the original
>   aspect ratio, do the following:
>
> 1) set adjustViewBounds to true
>
> 2) set
>   maxWidth and maxHeight to 100
>
> 3) set the height and width layout
>   params to WRAP_CONTENT.
>
> Note that this view could be still smaller than 100 x 100 using this
>   approach if the original image is small. To set an image to a fixed
>   size, specify that size in the layout params and then use
>   setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType) to determine how to
>   fit the image within the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Remove this line:

```
android:weightSum="100"
```

Step 2: Change 63 to 1 in this line:

```
android:layout_weight="63"
```

Step 3: Change the following lines:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="25"
```

to this ones:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

or if you want fixed width:

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:background="#E2E2E2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
                android:layout_weight="63"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:text="Captionjkdhka asdgasidga sgdia g Caption vCaptionCaptionCaptionvCaptionCaption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:text="Caption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textColor="#808080"
                    android:text="Caption"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="100"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:id="@+id/pub_date"
                    android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Issue was with height of your image view and layout